# Recommendation for where to learn web development in a classroom setting

Tags: language-agnostic

I've been doing server-side development for several years, and have not had much (read - practically no) web development experience.  My current employer is flush with ca$h at the moment and is offering to pay for training, so I thought it would be a great opportunity to learn.  I seem to learn best in a classroom setting with practice at home, so I was wondering if anyone had suggestions as to where would be a good place to learn this stuff.  There are some national firms that offer all kinds of training courses (e.g., LearningTree), but I have no idea how good they are.  Local college classes are an option too, as long as I don't have to go through a whole degree curriculum (I'm based in NYC/NJ).

Stuff I'd like to learn includes Servlets/JSPs (starting at a very basic level but quickly moving through advanced), Tomcat, MVC, and integration with frameworks such as Spring.  I realize not all of that may come bundled together in one neat little package, but if got 70% of the way there that would be a win too.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have friends who teach for Learning Tree, and they generally seem to know their stuff, but they spend most of their time teaching and working on small projects instead of large/enterprise application development.  Since they need at least one week a month of time to teach a course...  they can't always get hands-on experience in the bigger projects.

That said, if my company were flush on cash:

1. I'd try a single course at the most-convenient location near me.  Probably Learning Tree, as I respect the two instructors I know who work there.
2. But mainly, I'd simply ask for time off my primary projects to learn the technologies on my own.  If you install Tomcat and get a Hello World servlet built, then try to build an online cookbook site using Spring MVC on Tomcat, you'll have a really good knowledge of things in 40-80 hours.

You'll also have built the skills to continue learning on your own without paying someone else $3k a week to walk you through tutorials you can already find online.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  #2 is a good idea in theory, but corporate bureaucracy being what it is, it may be easier to take the course and the $3k than to ask for time off on my own - I don't think they'd feel as warm and fuzzy about it if I printed up my own "course completion certificate" as if I got it from LearningTree or whomever.